# How to use js to move a position:fixed element from A to B with animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

start point A position: (a, b);
end point B position: (x, y);
and the animation style:   `transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, -0.29, 0.75, 0.41);`

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do like that :

```js
let root = document.documentElement;

function moving() {
  root.style.setProperty('--pose-y', "150px");
  root.style.setProperty('--pose-x', "150px");
}
```

```css
:root {
--pose-x: 100px;
--pose-y: 0px;
}

.item {
left: var(--pose-x);
top: var(--pose-y);
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
position: fixed;
transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, -0.29, 0.75, 0.41);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<button onclick="moving()">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway, I choose to use anime.js eventually